# Import CSV from Gmail attachment into Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to import a CSV attachment of the latest email received from a specific email address into a Google Sheet.

I've used a collection of solutions found on this site and none seem to work for me. I'm importing an attachment from a Gmail message and all that gets imported into the Google sheet is a bunch of weird characters and question marks. It's almost looks like it imported the email itself in another font as opposed to the contents of the attachment.

If i switch the attachment.setContentType with the commented out alternative, then nothing gets imported at all.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

var threads = GmailApp.search("from:EMAIL ADDRESS");
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

// Is the attachment a CSV file

attachment.setContentType('text/csv'); 
//attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

// Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
 }
}
```

Actual results look something like this:

�PNG

"IHDR
�h*BĠW@1ࣨE�
o�$5���g�C)P$@�E(�HU��

Comment: That looks like a PNG graphics file.  Are you sure the attachment is a text file in Comma Delimited format?  also, is there a image file included such as might be found in the email signature?

Comment: You're right, that was the image file in the signature. I set getAttachment() to [1] inctead of [0] and that's done the trick!