# How do I add CSV or XLS content to next available row from Gmail into Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an email that comes everyday with an attached .xls (sometimes a CSV) spreadsheet file.
I would like to import this SS everyday and have the new content added to the next available rows.

How do I adjust this script to do that action?

I would like to have this script add the content to a specific sheet/tab.

In addition, how would I make this script look for a specific label instead of my primary inbox to pull the file from?

Reference of script: [Import CSV from Gmail attachment into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596814/import-csv-from-gmail-attachment-into-google-sheets)

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

var threads = GmailApp.search("from:Email Address Here");
var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[1];

// Is the attachment a CSV file

attachment.setContentType('text/csv'); 
//attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

// Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to append the CSV data and XLSX data to the specific tab in the active Spreadsheet.
- You want to retrieve emails with the specific label of the gmail.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- Data can be directly retrieved from CSV file. But in the case of XLSX file, it is required to convert it to Google Spreadsheet and retrieve the data from the converted Spreadsheet.

  - XLSX file is converted to Google Spreadsheet with Files: insert of Drive API.
- In order to append the data to the specific tab, in this modification, I used `getSheetByName()` and `getLastRow()`.
- In order to retrieve emails with the specific label, I used the search query of `label:###label###`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. And before you run the script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). And please set the tab name to `sheetName`. And please set the search query to `GmailApp.search("from:###email### label:###label###")`. `###email###` and `###label###` are the email address and the label, respectively.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the tab name you want to append the data.
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:###email### label:###label###"); // Please set here.

  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  var message = messages[messages.length - 1];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[1];
//  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension(); // This might be required for your situation.
  var data = [];
  if (attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.CSV) {
    data = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
  } else if (attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || attachment.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {
    var tempFile = Drive.Files.insert({title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, attachment).id;
    data = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempFile).getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    Drive.Files.trash(tempFile);
  }
  if (data.length > 0) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. I am following your instructions right now and will follow up with you shortly!

Comment: Question, if say the file type is a .xls, would I change `MimeType.CSV` to `MimeType.xls` ?

Comment: I'm getting this error message: "Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined. (line 5, file "Code")"

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. 1. The mimeType of `.xls` is `MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY`. This has already been set in this modified script. 2. `Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined. (line 5, file "Code")` indicates that the length of `threads[0]` is `0`. `GmailApp.search()` doesn't return no values. So please confirm the search query. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation because about the values for the search query are not due to the modified script. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: would it help if you had access to the sheet?

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying. If you cannot understand about my English, please tell me. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined. (line 5, file "Code")` and the Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about your current issue? Because I cannot understand whether my reply comment was useful for the issue you replying comment.

Comment: The current issue with the script is the error message that I notified you about. Have you tried this script using your own set up yet to test it out yourself?

Comment: I have a question I just thought of. Does this script assume to use my email based on my Google account that the script is being created from? Just wondering because the search operater for `from:###email###` is from the recipient and `label:###label###` is the name of the label. Do I not have to set my email to tell the script where to initially look first?

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying. In your question, there are 2 questions. In my answer for 1st question, the CSV data and XLSX data are appended to the specific tab in the active Spreadsheet. Also I answered for your 2nd question of `how would I make this script look for a specific label instead of my primary inbox to pull the file from?`. And it supposes that your current script in your question works. So the search query of `"from:###email### label:###label###"` retrieves emails with `###email###` AND `###label###` from your mailbox.

Comment: @FeatherDuster About the error message of `Cannot call method "getMessages" of undefined.`, this means that no emails are retrieved by the search query. This depends on the environment. In my environment, I could confirm that the modified script worked. Unfortunately, I cannot ask about the actual values of `###email###` AND `###label###` and your mailbox. So I would like to ask about your current script in your question before modifying. When you use the search query of `"from:Email Address Here"`, does the script work and can you retrieve some emails?

Comment: @FeatherDuster I would like to resolve your issue. So if you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I do a search query for `"from:email address here"` and take out `label:###label###`. Afterwards, I ran the script, and got this error message `Cannot call method "getContentType" of undefined. (line 10, file "Code")` and I do not retreive any emails. If it would make it easier for you, would you like to see my spreadsheet?

Comment: I also tried `from:email address here` and `label:name of label here`, ran the script and got the error message for `Cannot call method "getContentType" of undefined. (line 10, file "Code")` again.

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I have to confirm about your situation of your question. When you run the script of `importCSVFromGmail()` in your question, the script work fine. Is my understanding correct? Because in my answer, because I could understand that your script works fine, I proposed the modified script. I couldn't find that your initial script doesn't work from your question. If your initial script doesn't work, at first, the issue in the initial script has to be resolved.

Comment: Ah, sorry to have misunderstood you. The answer to your question would be no. The initial script never worked. Sorry to make you ask so many times. My bad on my part.

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation. At first, I would like to resolve the issue in your initial script. So can I ask you about the issue of your initial script? When you run your script in your question, what is the issue?

Comment: In my initial script I always get this error `Cannot call method "setContentType" of undefined. (line 10, file "Code")`.

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying. In your initial script, `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[1];` is used. In this case, 2nd attachment file is retrieved. If there is only one attachment file, how about modifying to `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];`? If the email doesn't have the attachment file, such error also occurs. Please be also careful this.

Comment: Holy shit, IT WORKED!! So after changing `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[1];` to `var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];` It imported my attachment. You're the man!! So when I initially set `[0]` to `[1]` that caused the variable to look for more than 1 attachment, by setting it to `[0]`, it by default only looks for 1. Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @FeatherDuster Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Yes. Your understanding is correct. If 2 attachment files are included in the email, 1st and 2nd files can be retrieved by `message.getAttachments()[0]` and `message.getAttachments()[1]`, respectively. The start index of an array is `0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your assistance on this, I'm sure alot of people will find this useful. My apologies for making it difficult the first time for you. Have a great day and again, big thank you!