# How do I import data from an Excel XLS gmail email attachment into a Google Sheet that overwrites the existing data

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Fairly new to Google Apps Scripting here, but I am pretty good with VBA. I receive a daily inventory report from my logistics provider by email. The attachment is an XLS file (Excel), and it is available in that format only. I have a previous google apps script (below) that will import the data from a CSV file attachment, and it works well, but all of the research and revising I have made to this script does not work correctly (and I have literally tried them all for the past two weeks). The email subject is "HBI Inventory Detail" and the exact filename of the attachment is "HBI Inventory Detail Email.xls". In addition, the only sheet in that spreadsheet is also named "HBI Inventory Detail Email". I would appreciate some direction and assistance with this--thank you so much!

Here is the existing code for the CSV script:

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

var threads = GmailApp.search("HBI Inventory Detail"); // enter search criteria here
var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZcuTKNxa9kVSxt36UyA5cpCqGDRVK6eCTsTcz20gxWw').getSheetByName('Data');
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

sheet.clearContents().clearFormats(); // clears target sheet
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData); // adds data to the sheet

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your script, the blob of XLS data is directly used with `var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");`. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the data cannot be directly retrieved from the blob of XLS data. I think that this is the reason for your issue.

When I saw your question, I thought that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58647644/7108653) might be useful. But, from `Fairly new to Google Apps Scripting here, but I am pretty good with VBA.` and your expected situation, I thought that when your goal is achieved by modifying your script, it might help to understand the script. So, in this answer, I would like to modify your script.

#### Modified script:

This script uses Drive API for converting XLS to Spreadsheet. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  // 1. Retrieve Blob of XLS data.
  var threads = GmailApp.search("HBI Inventory Detail");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  var csvData;
  var mimeType = attachment.getContentType();
  if (mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL || mimeType == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL_LEGACY) {

    // 2. Convert XLS to Google Spreadsheet as a temporal.
    var tempId = Drive.Files.insert({ title: "temp", mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS }, attachment).id;
    var tempsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempId).getSheets()[0];
    csvData = tempsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    DriveApp.getFileById(tempId).setTrashed(true);

  } else if (mimeType == MimeType.CSV) {

    // 3. If the data is CSV, this script is used.
    csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

  } else {
    console.log("Wrong mimeType.");
    console.log(mimeType);
    return;
  }
  if (csvData.length == 0) {
    console.log("No values.");
    return;
  }

  // 4. Put values.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZcuTKNxa9kVSxt36UyA5cpCqGDRVK6eCTsTcz20gxWw').getSheetByName('Data');
  sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

- In this modification, the value is retrieved from the 1st sheet of XLS data. If you want to retrieve the data from the specific sheet, please modify `getSheets()[0]` to `getSheetByName('###sheet name###')`.
- If the data is CSV data, `Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",")` is used.

#### References:

- [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert)
- Related thread.

  - [How do I add CSV or XLS content to next available row from Gmail into Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58647644/7108653)